# What to do when a question with an open bounty is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, exact-duplicates, bounty

Question

[Basic question about standard error in predictive model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323369/basic-question-about-standard-error-in-predictive-model)

is clearly a duplicate of either

[How to compute prediction bands for non-linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15423/how-to-compute-prediction-bands-for-non-linear-regression)

or

[Shape of confidence and prediction intervals for nonlinear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/shape-of-confidence-and-prediction-intervals-for-nonlinear-regression/85452#85452)

(the latter would be probably more appropriate for the OP). However, the question cannot be closed because there's an open bounty. What is the correct procedure in this case? Surely not to duplicate the answer...comment linking to the other questions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flag it.  Moderators can cancel bounties, refunding the reputation to the owner.

Comment: Funny, I answered that question and I was wandering how bounty disappeared.